# Interaction between 2 nodes of ganache

Tags: web3js, metamask, ganache

I am making a project on blockchain where in I am using ganache for private blockchain, meta mask to interact with the same.
Since ganache provides 10 nodes in the private blockchain, I want all the nodes or at least 2 of them to interact with the one another through UI.

For ex:
I have this UI running which I made in App.js file and on the UI there is an option of uploading a photo and after uploading, the picture is displayed on the same UI page.
What I want is, uploading part should be done by the another node of the ganache, after uploading the 1st node's UI should display the image. Image is stored on IPFS.